# Populating a table with a liquid template by iterating over an array (using liquid.js)

Tags: templates, liquid

I will be needing to implement Liquid templates using liquid.js and am wondering why I cannot get a basic table rendered when iterating over data. I may not render any table objects when the project starts (there are other posts that debate whether using tables with liquid is even appropriate), but it would be helpful to know why what I'm attempting fails. The Liquid tablerow object has not been ported over to liquid.js, so using it is not an option here.

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullcitydave/kat7tedu/), using basic list tags works to iterate over the array, but similar syntax with table tags does not.

Fails to render:

```
  <table>
      {% for pet in pets %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ pet.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ pet.type }}</td>
              <td>{{ pet.age }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Renders as expected:

```
  {% for pet in pets %}
  <ul>
      <li>{{ pet.name }}</li>
      <li>{{ pet.type }}</li>
      <li>{{ pet.age }}</li>
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullcitydave/kat7tedu/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to output liquid to simple tables by using CSS. I have done this for a simple inventory table. This HTML and CSS code should set you off in the right direction.

```
<ul class="pet-in-pets>
<li>{% liquid code here %} <br> {% more liquid %}</li>
</ul>
.pet-in-pets ul {  margin:0 0 15px;  width: 100%;  display: table;  table-layout: fixed; }
.pet-in-pets ul li {  display: table-cell;  width: auto;  text-align: center; border: 1px solid #fff; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ray. I can definitely output a table without using HTML table tags, and your code snippet illustrates very well how I could do that. However, I do want to understand why Liquid isn't playing well with HTML table tags. Nagging curiosity.